# Threejs render result looks bad

Tags: javascript, canvas, three.js, textures, rendering

I've created a canvas:

```
<canvas ref="canvas" width="512" height="512"></canvas>
```

I have such renderer:

```
 new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
      canvas: this.refs.canvas,
      antialias: true,
      alpha: true
 });
```

This renderer renders objects with `textures` whitch have size 512 X 512.

The problem is the textures on render result looks bad.
Then I increase canvas size in two times, let's say I make it 1024 x 1024 render result looks good.
I think that increasing canvas size is wrong way to reach a better render result, and must exist other way to reach good quality of render.
Can anybody tells me causes of such behaviour, and point me on rigth way how to handle it?
Here is example: http://jsfiddle.net/VsWb9/6806/

Comment: are you setting the size of the renderer?

Comment: @evilprofesseur Yes. I change canvas size and set size of the renderer + I set initial size to canvas via css. So canvas looks the same, but not blurred.

Comment: can you provide a fiddle?

Comment: @evilprofesseur http://jsfiddle.net/VsWb9/6806/ , see on the left canvas image quality much better than right canvas.

Comment: Your fiddle uses `CanvasRenderer`, not `WebGLRenderer`. Which one are you using? Also, please include the code of the fiddle in your post. When (not if) the fiddle goes away, so does the context of your question.